# Signature in Lotus Notes 8.5

Tags: mac, lotus-notes

How do you edit your signature in lotus notes version 8.5?

I'm using a Mac, if that has any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the inbox view, assuming you are on the full client and not the basic client, you click more-->preferences-->[mail]-->[signature].  The options for enabling the signature are pretty straight forward.

If you are on the basic client, I believe the options are the same as 7 and previous versions where you click Tools-->Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Crossware](http://www.crossware.co.nz/) software, you can add an email signature and or disclaimer to every transferred Lotus Notes email, with a professional layout.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.ehow.com/how_6199272_create-signature-lotus-notes-7.html) is a link for how to create a signature that holds HTML content, but one can use the same idea to make a non-html signature.

Comment: the tutorial doesn't apply to version 8.5 "Actions" doesn't have a "tools" section. Thanks for the pointer, though.

Comment: Sorry, its probably still called actions or similar though, in a primary menu.

Comment: The menus aren't arranged that way in 7 (the versions they claim to apply to) either.